# preg_replace_callback() not replace pattern with a function in class

Tags: php, preg-replace-callback

I ve a function in a class that replaces patterns. part of the function is below.

```
$text = preg_replace_callback('/\[dekanlik\]/',function (){return $this->dekanlik();},$text);
```

`dekanlik()` is another function in that class which lists the members.

works in local (PHP Version 5.4.21) but not work in server (PHP Version 5.3.3)

any suggestion?

Comment: [Turn on error reporting](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6575502/1438393) and see if you get any errors.

Answer (score 0):

Being able to reference the context of an anonymous function (i.e. use `$this`) has been added in PHP 5.4. Before than the common workaround was:

```
$that = $this;
... function () use ($that) { return $that->foo(); } ...
```